# OpenStack Dashboard Login page does not load

Tags: openstack, dashboard, horizon

I installed OpenStack Dashboard following Installation Guide here:
https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/wallaby/install/install-rdo.html

Not very compicated but Dashboad does not work. After the first access, there was only "Forbidden"
status for url http://localhost/dashboard/. Then I investigated /etc/httpd/conf.d/openstack-dashboard.conf file (it's content below) and noticed that the whole `wsgi` directory missing on the system. I tried to correct `WSGISriptAlias` to some another location in /usr/share/openstack-dashboard directory structure (for example, I tried with /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py) but it then status was *Not Found* and URL was redirected to http://localhost/auth/login/?next=/dashboard/.

I am not very familiar with web development so I don't completely understand what it means but after that I tried to find some solution on internet and I found this on Ask OpenStack:
https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/13952/horizon-apache-launch-error/

I tried with that solution but neither this helped me, after configuring the server according to that page, nothing appears on the page, only "Not Found". Please can someone help me to find some solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Here is content of the original /etc/httpd/conf.d/openstack-dashboard.conf file:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard
WSGIProcessGroup dashboard
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias /dashboard /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi
Alias /dashboard/static /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
  allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

to not bother you anymore with my stupid questions,
I found solution on another place which says that I have to add WEBROOT directive to
/etc/openstack-dashboard/Local_settings which was missing.

Thanks.
Regards.